# Content is appearing over bootstrap footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Guys I am new to web development and currently am creating website but I got stuck in footer problem. I am using bootstrap for styling and I thought bootstrap was pretty good for styling but I got a problem. My content is appearing over footer when I "ZOOM IN" OR "RESIZING TO IPAD PRO" my content is appearing on my footer and that's scary. I searched on whole internet but couldn't find any solution. So can you guys please help me out.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body>.container {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.content {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

a {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: coral;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.container.full-height {
    height: calc(100vh - 413px);
}

.site-footer {
    background-color: #26272b;
    padding: 61px 0 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #737373;
    height: 10%;
}

.site-footer hr {
    border-top-color: #bbb;
    opacity: 0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small {
    margin: 20px 0
}

.site-footer h6 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px
}

.site-footer a {
    color: #737373;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
    color: #3366cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none
}

.footer-links li {
    display: block
}

.footer-links a {
    color: #737373
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
    color: #3366cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
    display: inline-block
}

.copyright-text {
    margin: 0
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    .site-footer [class^=col-] {
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .site-footer {
        padding-bottom: 0
    }
    .site-footer .copyright-text,
    .site-footer {
        text-align: center
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
    .container.full-height {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title>Adnan Ullah Khan</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg justify-content-end">
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto container justify-content-center">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container full-height content">
         {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
      <footer class="site-footer mb-5">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                  <h6>About</h6>
                  <p class="text-justify">some line</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <p class="copyright-text">&copy; Copyright 2021
                     <a href="#"></a>.
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `margin-bottom: 3rem!important;` (`.mb-5` class) in footer ?

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Now I will give a solution

Comment: yes please give me a solution I have searched all over the internet but I only found one solution but when I applied solution When I zoom In content was not appearing over footer but another problem had risen and that is when I zoom out my footer was going up leaving down only whitespace but I didn't want that so you please help me so that my content don't appear over footer and when I zoom out it should be placed on very bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to anchor your `footer` to the bottom and not allow `content` to fit on it, follow this:

Take the rule to wrap in the main container.

```
<div class="main">
   <nav class="navbar">...</nav>
   <div class="container">...</div>
   <footer class="site-footer">...</footer>
</div>
```

These are the css rules for the `.main`:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

For stretching the main container remove rule `height: calc(100vh - 413px)` and add rule `flex: 1 0 auto` to `.container.full-height`. Like here:

```
.container.full-height {
    /*height: calc(100vh - 413px);*/
    flex: 1 0 auto;    
}
```

And push the `footer` down to add rule `flex: 0 0 auto` to `.site-footer`. Like this:

```
.site-footer {
    ...
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body>.container {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

a {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: coral;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.container.full-height {
    /*height: calc(100vh - 413px);*/
    flex: 1 0 auto;    
}

.site-footer {
    background-color: #26272b;
    padding: 61px 0 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #737373;
    height: 10%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.site-footer hr {
    border-top-color: #bbb;
    opacity: 0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small {
    margin: 20px 0
}

.site-footer h6 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px
}

.site-footer a {
    color: #737373;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
    color: #3366cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none
}

.footer-links li {
    display: block
}

.footer-links a {
    color: #737373
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
    color: #3366cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
    display: inline-block
}

.copyright-text {
    margin: 0
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    .site-footer [class^=col-] {
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .site-footer {
        padding-bottom: 0
    }
    .site-footer .copyright-text,
    .site-footer {
        text-align: center
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
    .container.full-height {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title>Adnan Ullah Khan</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg justify-content-end">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
               aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto container justify-content-center">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
         <div class="container full-height content">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Абзац 1.10.32 "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", написанный Цицероном в 45 году н.э.
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

Английский перевод 1914 года, H. Rackham
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"

Абзац 1.10.33 "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", написанный Цицероном в 45 году н.э.
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."

Английский перевод 1914 года, H. Rackham
"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
         </div>
         <footer class="site-footer">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                     <h6>About</h6>
                     <p class="text-justify">some line</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                     <p class="copyright-text">&copy; Copyright 2021
                        <a href="#"></a>.
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```